# Can I restrict certain users from certain dashboards in Kibana without using xpack

Tags: kibana, xpack

Im trying to let certain users/roles only access certain dashboards.

Maybe customer1 can only see dashboards 1 & 2

customer2 can see 1, 2 & 3.

Using opendistro so I dont have access to x-pack

Answer (score 0):

You can certain option using by [opensource distro of elasticsearch](https://opendistro.github.io/for-elasticsearch/).

This is Amazon implementation based on elasticsearch opensource under Apache 2 license part.

This is features implemented on this elasticsearch, kibana fork:

[image]